# Replicating a PHP POST request in Java

Tags: java, php, rest, post, php-curl

I have this working PHP script that makes a POST request to an old server (which i don't have access to). I need to write a REST api in Java/Spring that handles all communication with this old server. I do, however, keep getting the following exception:

> SSLHandshakeException: DH ServerKeyExchange does not comply to algorithm constraints

My guess is that the server has too low a security level (which i can't change). The PHP script sets a SSL cipher list, which i don't know how to replicate in Java. And hence the question is, how do i lower the security level of my Java application such that it can communicate with the server?

The php code:

```
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf8'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,4);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, "AES128-SHA");
$response = curl_exec($ch);
echo $response;
```

The Java code i wrote:

```
CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
    
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(json));

CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost); //Here SSLHandshakeException occurs
    
String result = getResultStringFromResponse(response);
    
client.close();
return result;
```

I have very limited experience with POST requests in general and have been working on this problem for several days without any progress. Any guidance/tips will be much appreciated!

Comment: Is your java code running on same server as that of php code. May be there is some validation of IP address.

Comment: Both are simply running on a localhost server

Comment: could you try .setHeader(HttpHeaders.CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, "AES128-SHA") like in https://www.baeldung.com/httpclient-custom-http-header

Comment: HttpHeaders doesn't have a field named anything with SSL or cipher list. Is there one of its other fields that can be used for similar purpose?

It's fields can be seen at: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpHeaders.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:

I managed to solve this issue by removing the key constraint that java requires for http requests.

This was done by going to my jdk folder and removing "DH keySize < 1024" in the file /conf/security/java.security. That change made java accept low security level of the server. If anybody knows how to do it at runtime instead (such that is only for that specific POST request) that would be a much better solution.